# Selecting a value on mat-autocomplete clears the value and then displays full list?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In angular with material, I'm trying to create a search bar that displays what they user types in. Right now it is displaying what the user types in until they select an option from the drop down list. Once they select an option from the drop down list, it displays the full list again for some reason. I cannot seem to figure out why this is.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
            <mat-form-field class="input col-lg-12">
                <mat-label>Search Teams By Team Name</mat-label>
                <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.teamName">
                        {{option.teamName}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div *ngFor="let game of filteredOptions | async"  class="col-lg-6 card-background align card-surround shadow-sm">
          <div id="background">
                <div>
                    <h1>{{game.teamName}} Vs. {{game.awayTeamName}}</h1>
                    <button class="btn full-width btn-success">Vote</button>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is my typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Teams {
  teamName: string;
  awayTeamName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-of-the-week-voting',
  templateUrl: './game-of-the-week-voting.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-of-the-week-voting.component.scss']
})

export class GameOfTheWeekVotingComponent implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  games = [];
  options: Teams[] = [
    {teamName: 'Oklahoma', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'Iowa', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'Kansas State', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'Iowa State', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'Baylor', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'FSU', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'Cal', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'Syracuse', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'Ohio State', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'UNLV', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'Michigan', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'Kansas', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'Oklahoma State', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'Texas', awayTeamName: 'test'},
    {teamName: 'Texas Tech', awayTeamName: 'test'},
  ];
  filteredOptions: Observable<Teams[]>;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
  }

  displayFn(team: Teams): string {
    return team && team.teamName ? team.teamName : '';
  }

  test(test) {
    console.log(test)
  }

  private _filter(name: string): Teams[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();
    // console.log(this.options.filter(option => option.teamName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0));
    return this.options.filter(option => option.teamName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }

  onSubmit() {

  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you have a stackblitz?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot seem to get it to work with material on stack blitz.